# htaccess allow if page number is supplied or not supplied

Tags: apache, .htaccess

**Eg:**

```
RewriteRule ^/?(us|uk)/(national|regional)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /fetch/index.php?country=$1&scope=$2&page=$3 [NC,L]
```

In the above rule, the last part `([a-z0-9]+)` specifies the page number. The page number may be there or may not be there. In both cases, the rule should work. Is it possible to do this?

Right now, I have one rule for when a page number is supplied, and another for when it's not.

How can I write a single rule that'll get through when a page number is supplied and even when not?

**So:**

```
http://www.example.com/us/national/ -> allowed with no page number
http://www.example.com/us/national/pg3 -> allowed with page number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the + to a * in the last segment should do it

Comment: That worked. Turns out I need to provide a `/` after the second one for it to work without the page number.